# Is there a way to prevent a style property from being set on a DOMNode?

Tags: javascript, css

Assuming my component has a DOMNode (As simple as a `<div>`) that a different component can also control.

Is there a way I can prevent a style property from being set via JS by the other component?

For eg, I have set `domNode.style.color = "blue"`, Can I prevent someone from setting inline style `color` on this same `domNode`?

If this was CSS, I could control specificity, not sure how this can be done via JS.

(I am limited to using ES5)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: No, not directly. Shadow DOM would be a way to encapsulate your component from “other stuff” though.

Comment: You could probably do something elaborate with [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but I doubt it would be worth it.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to do that, if you want to ensure that no one can break your styles, the only way is to use the `!important` flag in css

```
#mydiv {
 color: black!important; /* color will be always black */
}
```

Comment: I can still override that using JavaScript: `domNode.style.color = "blue !important";`...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent changing the inline CSS of a DOM node in JavaScript.  However, I have come up with a workaround.

1. Set a `data-` value on the element when you do not want it to be changed again.
2. Then, when the other component wants to change the color property, have it check if the value you have set exists, and if it is, then abort the style change.

Comment: Or are you unable to edit the code for the other component?